# Will shared object data disappear when the user updates the app?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, shared-objects

I'm using Flash and AS3 to write an app for iOS and for Android and I'm saving XML-data using shared objects. Now it struck me that when I supply an update to the app store and the user updates the app, will the shared objects remain intact or will they be replaced? I'd very much like them to remain as they were. How does it work and what should be done if it causes a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the answer. According to Saumitra Bhave the Wise, in this thread http://www.saumitrabhave.com/2011/11/air-ios-solving-apps-must-follow-ios.html
the shared objects will remain even after the user updates the app. Which is great.